# how to pass all the column from dataframe into different user defined function

Tags: python, regex, pandas

How to pass all the column from dataframe into different user defined function

here is mine dataframe look like

```
    data = [['tom', 10, 9876765143, 'SUN 1023'], ['nick', 15, 98767654312, 'SUN 1023'], ['juli', 14, 98769876541, 'SUN 1023']]    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age', 'Number', 'Address'])         
    df
```

here are function right now i am just showing one function

```
        def number(inp):
            import re
            regex = r'^\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*(\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{4})(?: *x(\d+))?\s*$'
            inp = inp.replace(regex, 'XXXXXXX')
            print (inp)

  number(df.Number)
```

It throws error

```
     ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

similarly i have multiple function i just want to pass each column from dataframe with the value associated within the column of dataframe into each user defined function  like i have a function number similarly i have other function def new() def beg() one by one.
Is there any way to solve that problem

Comment: I run your code and see no error, the result is: 0     9876765143
1    98767654312
2    98769876541

Comment: 0  1 and 2 are indexes, 0:9876765143 1:98767654312 2:98769876541

Comment: i want to use it in a function and i have several other regex too even i have to apply multiple regex to a single column. I just want to pass each column into all the user defined function one by one is it possible?

Comment: I am not sure if i fully understand what you want, you have more than one function and every function is designed to apply regrex to specific column of the dataframe,is that right?

Answer (score 2):

Why even use a function? You can directly apply the regex pattern to the relevant column(s).

```
regex = r'^\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*(\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{4})(?: *x(\d+))?\s*$'

>>> df['Number'].astype(str).str.replace(regex, 'XXXXXXX')
0    XXXXXXX
1    XXXXXXX
2    XXXXXXX
Name: Number, dtype: object
```

If you need a function:

```
import random

def phone_number(series):
    regex = r'^\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*(\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{4})(?: *x(\d+))?\s*$'
    return series.str.replace(regex, 'X' * random.randrange(3, 8))

>>> phone_number(df['Number'].astype(str))
0    XXXXXXX
1    XXXXXXX
2    XXXXXXX
Name: Number, dtype: object
```

Comment: Hey @Alexander i want to use it in a function and i have several other regex too even i have to apply multiple regex to a single column. I just want to pass each column into all the user defined function one by one is it possible?

Comment: How to iterate all such function to each and every column in dataframe

Comment: Can i generate random length 'XXXXX'

Comment: To apply it to all columns in the dataframe: `{col: phone_number(df[col].astype(str)) for col in df}`. For specific columns, just replace `df` with a list of the relevant columns.  You could generate random length `XXXXX`, but that sounds like a separate question.

Comment: As i think i just need to use randint to generate  random  lenghth  'XXXXX' if you could answer me that will be become easy for me thanks anyway

Comment: Between how many characters? Each column can have its own random length string of `X`, e.g. `XXXX`.  Doing that for each row requires a different approach and is a separate question.